# Uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected identifier in chrome console SCRIPT1003: expected ':' in IE

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am unable to show data provided from database in the google chart. I am constantly getting the same error in chrome console.

Uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected identifier in chrome console SCRIPT1003: expected ':' in IE

@model IEnumerable

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDualY);

function drawDualY() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Topic');
data.addColumn('string', 'Test');
data.addColumn('string', 'Retest');


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
@: data.addRows[{@item.TTopic},@item.TScoreTest,@item.TScoreRetest],
}

var options = {
chart: {
title: 'Employee Score Card',

},
series: {
0: {axis: ''},
1: {axis: ''}
},
axes: {
y: {
MotivationLevel: {label: 'Test Score'},
EnergyLevel: {label: 'Restest Score'}
}
},
hAxis: {
title: 'Test Topic',
format: '',
viewWindow: {
min: [9, 30, 0],
max: [17, 30, 0]
}
},
vAxis: {
title: 'Employee Score'
}
};

var materialChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
materialChart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this type of error can often be a misplaced comma in an object or array definition:ie.

```
 var obj = {
   id: 23,
   name: "test",  <--
}
```

If it appears at a random line, maybe it's part of an object defintion you are creating dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

var options = {
chart: {
title: **'Employee Score Card',**

You have an extra comma after 'Employee Score Card',